# why i can't see all phrases i wrote in the textView?

Tags: android, textview, full-text-search

i create a linear with 2 TextView like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/popup_message"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:text="@string/atten"
          android:id="@+id/title"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingLeft="30px"
          android:paddingTop="15dp"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="@string/msg"
          android:id="@+id/msg"
          android:textColor="@color/littleBlack"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingRight="10dp"
          android:textScaleX="1"
          android:paddingLeft="25dp"
          android:paddingTop="10dp"></TextView>
```

when i include this on other pages sometime i  see the full text sometime no . any idea ? ps : forgive my english

Comment: You will need to explain a little more when it shows and when it doesn't.

Comment: when i was looking for some data and data was empty i show this layout with a specific msg like " element not find please try again" and in other page i saw " element not find"

Answer (score 0):

I see, you're messing a lot with the measurements of your views. The best way is to always use `sp` or `dip` to measure your view. `px` can be used only if your targeting a specific device. Try resolving this problem and maybe you'll find the answer.